# Pass functions to front-end angular from back-end node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, api, post

**Introduction**

I need to verify if a email address is within a API, if so allow a user to enter a section someone cant if they are not a user.

I have built the back-end node code to verify this.

I have 3 functions build in my back-end `(node, express)`.

**The first**

Gets data from a front-end form `(Angular)` post and then uses `promise` to make the value available to the third function.

**The second**

This function authenticates and gets my API key and using promise makes this function available to the third function.

**The third**

This function uses the data from the first (email address) and the API key from the second and post to a API endpoint, If the email is present on the API you get pass, if not fail.

**Process**

A user enters a email on the front end Angular, hits `login` then this email is passed to the three back-end functions, then it will pass or fail in the third function.

If this passes I wish to pass `$scope.EmailTrue= true;` to my Angular controller so that I can `ng-hide` or `ng-show` buttons on my front-end.

I was thinking of maybe a simple post to my front-end, but I am new to angular and node so I am unaware if there is a different way of doing this.

**Node back-end (3 functions)**

```
//---------------------------------- Grab the packages we need and set variables ---------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var nodePardot = require('node-pardot');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var rp = require('request-promise');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// Credential's for pardot API
var password = 'password';
var userkey = 'userkey';
var emailAdmin = 'admin@admin.com';

// Start the server
app.listen(port);
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); // support encoded bodies
console.log('Test server started! At http://localhost:' + port); // Confirms server start

//---------------------------------- Function to get front end form posted data LOGIN form ----------------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var firstFunction = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            app.post('/back-end/test', function (req, res) {
                console.log(req.body);
                var login = req.body.LoginEmail;
                res.send(login);
                resolve({
                    data_login_email: login
                });
            });
            console.error("First done");
        }, 2000);
    });
};

//---------------------------------- Function to get API key from Pardot (AUTHENTICATION) ------------------------------
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
var secondFunction = function () {
    return new Promise (function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            nodePardot.PardotAPI({
                userKey: userkey,
                email: emailAdmin,
                password: password,
                DEBUG: false
            }, function (err, client) {
                if (err) {
                    // Authentication failed
                    console.error("Authentication Failed", err);
                } else {
                    // Authentication successful
                    var api_key = client.apiKey;
                    console.log("Authentication successful !", api_key);
                    resolve({data_api: api_key});
                }
            });
            console.error("Second done");
        }, 2000);
    });
};

//---------------------------------- Function to post data to Pardot ---------------------------------------------------
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function thirdFunction(result) {
    return new Promise (function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            var headers = {
                'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            };
// Configure the request
            var api = result[1].data_api;
            var login_email = result[0].data_login_email;
            var options = {
                url: 'https://pi.pardot.com/api/prospect/version/4/do/read',
                method: 'POST',
                headers: headers,
                form: {
                    'email': login_email,
                    'user_key': userkey,
                    'api_key': api
                },
                json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
            };

// Start the request
            rp(options)
                .then(function (parsedBody) {
                    console.error("pass");
                    // $scope.FormLogin = true;
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.error("fail");
                });
            console.error("Third done");
        }, 3000);
    }
    );
}

// sequence of functions
Promise.all([firstFunction(), secondFunction()])
    .then(thirdFunction);
```

**Angular controller**

```
FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function TestController($scope, $http) {
    $scope.LoginForm = function () {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.formData.LoginEmail
        };

    $http({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/test',
        method: "POST",
        data: data,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    }).success(function (data) {
        $scope.formData = data; // assign  $scope.persons here as promise is resolved here
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.formData = status;
    });

}
});
```

**Angular view**

```
<form class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
    <div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email*</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control col-sm-12" name="LoginEmail" placeholder="Enter valid E-mail">
        </div>

        <button class=""
                ng-submit="LoginForm()">
            Login<span class=""></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can user the `$http` service to make an http request and then handle the response.

You can do:

```
$http.post('/login', {
    email: 'user@email.com',
    password: 'pwd'
}).then(response => {
    // use http status code
    if (response.status === 403) {
        alert('forbidden')'
    } else {
        // do something
    }
})
```

Comment: How would I link this with my node backend if pass or fail ?